# Copy file in Ant to dynamic directory name

Tags: file, ant, copy

I need to copy a file using ant from one folder to the other.
I know the exact name of the src file but for the destination file it's unknown since it's a version based folder I used the following script but it didn't work (please notice the * in the todir attribute:

```
<copy todir="${env.WORKSPACE}/my_dist_folder*" >
    <fileset dir="${env.WORKSPACE}/my_src_folder">
         <exclude name="**/*.svn"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Please Advice!
Thanks

Comment: could you post some samples of your `my_dist_folder` ?

Comment: this is the name of the folder!

Comment: *`the destination file it's unknown since it's a version based folder`* .. i'm guessing the **dest. folder name** would be of the form `my_dist_folder_<version id>`. so, what could be the **possible values** of you destination folder ?

Comment: my_dist_folder-9.7.0-v0013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming there may be multiple `my_dist_folder-xx..` folders:

```
<!-- goups all directories of the form "my_dist_folder-xx" -->
<dirset id="dir_list" dir="${env.WORKSPACE}">
  <include name="my_dist_folder*"/>
</dirset>
<!-- generate path names of the above dirs and sort them -->
<pathconvert property="dir_names_list" refid="dir_list" pathsep=","/>
<sortlist property="sorted_names_list" value="${dir_names_list}" delimiter="," />
<!-- pick the last path-name (as it corresponds with the latest version-number directory ) -->
<propertyregex property="dist_folder" input="${sorted_names_list}" regexp=",?([^,]+)$" select="\1"/>
<!-- use this "dist_folder" as "todir" in the copy task -->
<copy todir="${dist_folder}" >
    <fileset dir="${env.WORKSPACE}/my_src_folder">
         <exclude name="**/*.svn"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

although, from your question, it appears that all such `my_dist_folder-xx..` folders would be directly under the basedir `${env.WORKSPACE}`... in case they may be under sub-directories within the basedir, then replace the line `<include name="my_dist_folder*"/>` with `<include name="**/my_dist_folder*"/>` in the `<dirset>` task.

**UPDATE**: also, if you're sure that there'll always be only **one** such folder `my_dist_folder-xx..` on the system, then you may remove the following two lines- `<sortlist>` and `<propertyregexp>`, because the `<dirset>` will generate only **one path-name** and therefore you won't need to sort/pick-the-last-one. so you may use the `<pathconvert>` property to directly set the **destination folder**. eg:

```
<dirset id="dir_list" dir="${env.WORKSPACE}">
  <include name="my_dist_folder*"/>
</dirset>
<!-- generate path name of the above dir -->
<pathconvert property="dir_names_list" refid="dir_list" pathsep=","/>   
<!-- use this "dir_names_list" as "todir" in the copy task -->
<copy todir="${dir_names_list}" >
    <fileset dir="${env.WORKSPACE}/my_src_folder">
         <exclude name="**/*.svn"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```